# How to know that user selected some row in DBGrid?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I have DBGrid and button "Delete" outside DBGrid. How I can determine, that user selected some string in DBGrid? Because if the form opens and no strings selected in DBGrid, and user clicked the button "Delete" - I need to show him the alert box "No strings selected! Select the string you want to delete."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the DBGrid1.SelectedRows

```
procedure TForm24.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BookmarkList: TBookmarkList;
  Bookmark: TBookmark;
  i: Integer;
begin
  BookmarkList := DBGrid1.SelectedRows;

  if BookmarkList.Count = 0 then
    ShowMessage('No strings selected! Select the string you want to delete')
  else
  begin
    for i := 0 to BookmarkList.Count - 1 do
    begin
      ClientDataSet1.GotoBookmark(BookmarkList[i]);
      ClientDataSet1.Delete;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `DBGrid1->DataSource->DataSet->IsEmpty()`. This string always show FALSE. Even if some string selected in DBGRID.

Comment: @Jens - I think you may be confusing the concept of a "selected record" with the **current** record.  There is always a current record, unless the data set is empty, but depending on the settings of the grid there may be o, 1 or many records **selected**.

Comment: Strange, but `DBGrid1->SelectedRows->Count` always shows 0. Even if the row selected. dgRowSelect is true. I solved this problem changed dgAlwaysShowSelected to TRUE. Now it always some row is selected.

Comment: @Art - you really need to post more code to show how your implementation is expecting the grid to work, how it is configured, and why the current behaviour does not meet your needs and expectations.

Comment: I see this answer has now been accepted, which I think is poor form given that the original version of this answer was wrong and the replacement version, updated only after I commented on its wrongness, is now based on **my** answer posted before this one was modified.  Very poor form indeed.  imho.  But as long as Art solved his problem, that's all that really matters.

Comment: @Deltics:  Indeed.  Hopefully the upvotes on your answer will catch future readers' eyes.

Answer (score 7):

You do not say whether your grid is set to use **dgRowSelect** and/or **dgMultiSelect** or not.  If it is, then the list of currently selected rows is available as a list of bookmarks via the **SelectedRows** property.

If there are no selected records then this list will be empty so:

```
if myGrid.SelectedRows.Count = 0 then
  // Nothing selected!
```

Comment: This will work only when `dgMultiSelect` is true. Then user may delete more than one record.

Comment: Yes, the question is not clear on this point which is why I specifically point out "**If** it is [*set to dgMultiSelect*]" ?